# why does a batch file throws an error file not found while run using windows scheduler

Tags: batch-file

I'm not a pro-coder, I'm working in an organisation where during the work.
I have to unzip a large zip file which usually take an hour or two to be unzipped and then I have to copy the unzipped contents to different locations. since unzipping is time taking I just wrote a batch file to unzip and copy the output to desired locations just in a couple of clicks.

Zipped file name is DDMMYYYY.zip (say if the date is 15/06/2019 File name would be 15062019.zip)

This is for WIndows 7 Professional. I have written a batch file which reads the current date of the system and unzips the zip file and copies the Unzipped content to different locations. It runs flawlessly when run by double-clicking the file or by calling it thru another batch file

I tried to automate it (say it will run automatically when the clock hits 11:55 pm) using windows scheduler. but after scheduling the task as soon as the timer expires command prompts opens but it says it could not find the file which is to be unzipped. here again, if I double click the batch file it does everything as expected. what should be done to overcome the problem

I am adding the code here (I am using mobile to access Internet to please ignore syntax error in the code)

```
cd c:\program files (x86)\winrar
Set /p new_folder=“enter date”
Winrar.exe x -ibck c:\data\%new_folder%.zip c:\%new_folder%
Copy c:\%new_folder%\*.jpg c:\img_data
Robocopy c:\%new_folder%\ “\\client IP\c$\img_data” /e
Pause
```

There are 5 more robocopy commands which copy files to five more destination folders.

Comment: That's probably because you didn't either set the current directory within your batch file, or provide the fully qualified paths to your files. You've not made any effort to provide us with the code you've written which isn't working as intended, I'm therefore not going to make any futher effort until you do.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. i dont have the code right now. let me expalin it  a little firther.  i have Unzip.bat and file 15062019.zip. if i double click Unzip.bat it does every diesred thing, but thru windows scheduler it thows the error file not found. i have to solve this. Pleaae help

Comment: You told us, "I have written a batch file which reads the current date of the system and unzips the zip file and copies the Unzipped content to different locations. It runs flawlessly when run by double-clicking the file or by calling it thru another batch file", but apparently don't have the code right now. When you've got that and have posted it as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56646923/edit), we may be able to "please help", until then no, we cannot! I have marked your question for closing.

Comment: giving us your code is probably a good starting place.

Comment: Please make sure that you're using quotation marks, e.g. `"\\client IP\c$\img_data"`, not `“\\client IP\c$\img_data”`.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that your batch file assumes that it is running in the correct directory, but chances are the scheduler is running it from a totally different location.

To test this, try having the first thing the batch file does is display the current directory - eg insert something like this as the first line :

```
echo %cd%
```

The fix, needless to say, would be to have the first thing the batch file does is go to its directory.

Comment: Exactly this, but to add more information, task scheduler starts in `C:\Windows\System32` and scripts that use relative paths to files should start with `cd %~dp0`.